# dropdown menu KivyMD dosent shows

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm new on kivy/kivymd and I am trying to create a dropdown menu through the kivymd documentation. However, whenever I click on the dropdown it returns this error to me:
app.dropdown.open(self)
TypeError: open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

from kivymd.app import MDApp
import win32api

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]

class YouTubeDownloader(MDApp):
    dropdown = ObjectProperty()
    def on_start(self):
        self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu()
        for i in drives:
            self.dropdown.items.append(
                {"viewclass":"MDMenuItem",
                 "text":str(i),
                 "callback": self.menu_callback
                 }
            )    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        print(text_item)

YouTubeDownloader().run()
```

KV file

```
    BoxLayout:
    orientation:"vertical"
    MDToolbar:
        title:"YouTube Downloader"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color

    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Enter the URL here"
            size_hint: 0.4,0.15
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
        MDRaisedButton:
            id: dropdown
            text: "Select Path"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
            on_release:
                app.dropdown.open(self)
            
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            AsyncImage:
                id: image
                source: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LRXo0juuTrw/maxresdefault.jpg"
            AsyncImage:
                source: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LRXo0juuTrw/maxresdefault.jpg"
            AsyncImage:
                source: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LRXo0juuTrw/maxresdefault.jpg"
            AsyncImage:
                source: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/LRXo0juuTrw/maxresdefault.jpg"
        MDRaisedButton:
            text:"Download"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5}
```

on running this code i get an error saying

```
app.dropdown.open(self)
 TypeError: open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

can anybody help??

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
app.dropdown.open(self)
```

By:

```
app.dropdown.open()
```